# How to include two subfigures using the subfig-package instead of subcaption package

Tags: subfloats

So far, I have included two subfigures in my LaTeX document, using the `caption` and the `subcaption` packages. But now I am given a Template, that only uses the `subfig` package. Can somebody tell me how to change the following code, such that it includes the two subfigures next to each other, in a Template that only has `subfig` package?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \input{pic/PSB_amplitude}
      \caption{AM/AM}
      \label{sub1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \input{pic/PSB_phase}
      \caption{AM/PM}
      \label{sub2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Nonlinear characteristics.}
    \label{threebox}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Do not allow the template to become a dictator. Simply replace package `subfig` by `subcaption`, if you like to use `subcaption` instead of `subfig`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Some classes are incompatible with `caption` and `subcaption`; for instance, `revtex4-1`.

Comment: @egreg If there would be a MWE or at least some more information in the question we would not need to speculate about such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case that you will not consider advice in comment of *Schweinebacke*:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[AM/AM\label{sub1}]{\input{pic/PSB_amplitude}}
\hfil
    \subfloat[AM/PM\label{sub2}]{\input{pic/PSB_phase}}
    \caption{Nonlinear characteristics.}
    \label{threebox}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I want to have a label for the complete figure as well. I have tried to just put '\label{Fig1}' directly behind the [h] in the first line. But it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: Usually a caption should be sufficient for description of figure. Labels are part of image. What is purpose of label? If you will provide complete MWE, I will be able to see, what I can do.